# Visual Studio change build output path for single file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

Is there some relatively easy way I can have the build procedure output a file to a different directory than where it exists in the project?

In the attached snapshot, I want to move the `/client/scripts/app/customer.js` file into the `/App/Customers` folder for easy grouping during dev time, but of course need the actual js file outputted to the client directory.

[image]

If this can be done, is there some way to make it easily repeatable/manageable? (e.g., something not quite hackish or at least fairly repeatable as I'd like this to be a standard setup type of thing).  I've already re-written the view engines so all my MVC stuff is grouped by entity (which is awesome), but I still have to scroll away from my "group" to get my script file...

Comment: *I still have to scroll away* actually you don't: you can have both folders open each in their own seperate solution explorer (right-click folder, 'New Solution Explorer View'). Or, ditch that mouse all together and use Ctrl-T (Edit->Navigate To, or the Resharper equivalent) ans start typing.

Answer (score 0):

@jdl134679, you could copy specified files to target folder by using Copy task.